# How do you get in the desert in Ocarina of Time?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I'm trying to get in the desert but I can't find the way in.

I already got the membership card.

Answer (score 15):

Once you beat Gerudo Fortress and gain the membership card (see [this walkthrough for example](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Gerudo_Fortress)), speak with the guard that is up the top of a ladder next to the big gate. She'll let you through to the next area.

You have to use the longshot to cross to the other side of the quicksand, and then follow the red flags until you reach a small tower.

Put on the lens of truth and follow the ghost that you can see.
At the end of this area you'll arrive in the Desert Colossus.

Comment: I've just played through this. You can also use Hover boots instead of hookshot.

Comment: The first paragraph is sufficient to answer the question I think. The other info might be unwanted spoilers